# Python Pandas module fills a column in a DataFrame with NaN, even though the input is a column from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
text =  pd.DataFrame(["it", "never", "forget", "it", "hello", "listener's", "books", "at", "cya", "in", "the", "village", "deliberate", "mistake", "hello", "again", "i'd", "seen", "the", "thing", "and", "i'd", "love", "to", "check"])

c_mask = text[0] == "i'd"
v_mask = c_mask.shift(fill_value=False)

check_c = pd.DataFrame()
check_c["contractions"] = text[c_mask]
check_c["followup"] = text[v_mask]
print(check_c)

Out[46]
   contractions followup
16          i'd      NaN
21          i'd      NaN
```

For the life of me can't figure this out!

```
check_c["contractions"] = text[c_mask]

check_c["followup"] = text[v_mask]
```

These two lines are identical as far as I can see. Moreover, doing the "followup" column first then the "contractions", makes "followup" fill normally, and "contractions" with NaN. I thought it might be an index issue, but using .reset_index() method didn't help, and converting the second line to Series before trying to add it as a column didn't help either. Can someone please explain what's going on and why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this, by editing the second line:

```
check_c["followup"] = text.loc[v_mask,0].values
```

I guess it was an issue with index, but I am still unsure. If someone could explain what actually happens there, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is different index issue, because shifted mask, so new column is filled by `NaN`s, because for second mask not exist `index=17,22`.

```
print(text[v_mask])
       0
17  seen
22  love

print(text[c_mask])
      0
16  i'd
21  i'd
```

Another problem is one column Dataframe, so cannot create 1d array, if want assign like in your solution, need `Series`:

```
print(text[v_mask].to_numpy())
[['seen']
 ['love']]

print(text.loc[v_mask, 0].to_numpy())
['seen' 'love']
```

Your solution not working if `"i'd"` is last value of column, because array return only one element and `ValueError` raised:

```
text =  pd.DataFrame(["it", "never", "forget", "it", "hello", "listener's",
                      "books", "at", "cya", "in", "the", "village", "deliberate", 
                      "mistake", "hello", "again", "i'd", "seen", "the", "thing",
                      "and", "i'd"])


c_mask = text[0] == "i'd"
v_mask = c_mask.shift(fill_value=False)


print (text.loc[v_mask,0].values)
['seen']

check_c = pd.DataFrame()
check_c["contractions"] = text[c_mask]
check_c["followup"] = text.loc[v_mask,0].values
```

> ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (2)

I suggest first shift and then filter:

```
c_mask = text[0] == "i'd"

check_c = pd.DataFrame()
check_c["contractions"] = text.loc[c_mask, 0]
check_c["followup"] = text.shift(-1).loc[c_mask, 0]
print(check_c)
   contractions followup
16          i'd     seen
21          i'd     None
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the shift method returns a Series, and the data type of the resulting Series will be the same as the original Series. In your case, the data type of both c_mask and v_mask will be pandas Series with boolean values.

therefore you can apply v_mask logic directly to filteration for shift for new column, check below correct code.

```
import pandas as pd

text = pd.DataFrame(["it", "never", "forget", "it", "hello", "listener's", "books", "at", "cya", "in", "the", "village", "deliberate", "mistake", "hello", "again", "i'd", "seen", "the", "thing", "and", "i'd", "love", "to", "check"])

c_mask = text[0] == "i'd"
print(c_mask)


check_c = pd.DataFrame()
print(check_c)
check_c["contractions"] = text[0]
print(check_c)

# Shift the v_mask one more time to get the correct "followup" row
check_c["followup"] = text[0].shift(periods=-1, fill_value=False)

# Filter rows where "i'd" is present in "contractions"
result_df = check_c.loc[c_mask]

print(result_df)
```